# Write a script to output modified javascript

Tags: javascript, bash, scripting

I have javascript files that use an IP address that changes when I move it. I figured I could write a script that parses through my many javascript files and replaces a token string like `%IP_ADDRESS%` with the result fetched from `ifconfig`. The resulting file buffer gets saved as the usable scripts for my site.

Is there an easier way to achieve this? If not, what bash commands would help me scan files, replace tokens, and save to a new file?

Thanks

Comment: You could probably consider having one master file that holds things like the IP address (or whatever).  Load those values on the fly.  Have a specific file for each server it runs on.

Comment: @durbnpoisn how do you do that in javascript

Comment: I'll throw in an answer to show...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I threw this together as a really quick demo.

[Click here to view result](http://dpoisn.com/demos/demo.html)

Here is the code for the HTML page.  You can view the result from above.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dpoisn.com/demos/vars.js"></script>
<head>
<title>DPoisn.com - demo Page</title>
</head
<body>

    <div id="demo">blank for now</div>

    <script type="text/JavaScript" language="JavaScript">
        messageIs = "ipIs: " + ipIs + "<br />hostIs: " + hostIs;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  messageIs

    </script>

<p>source for vars.js:</p>

<pre><code>
var ipIs = '198.168.1.1'
var hostIs = 'http://dpoisn.com'
</code></pre>

</body>
</html>
```

All this does is pull in a .js file that holds that variables you need.  As long as that import is done before everything else on the page, you can make use of whatever is inside it.  In this case, setting a couple of strings.

The idea is that you can have a "vars.js" that is unique to every server you run it on.  And you can use the variables without ever having to change the code throughout the site again.

Comment: Some javascripts aren't embedded in html

Comment: It doesn't matter where the Javascripts are.  They could be embedded, or external.  The point here is to use one central spot to hold all your environment variables.  However you go about using them is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sed`. If you get the IP address into the variable `$ip`, you can do:

```
sed "s/%IP_ADDRESS%/$ip/g" template.js > script.js
```

Comment: Thank you this is what I wanted to know

Answer (score 0):

> what bash commands would help me scan files, replace tokens, and save to a new file?

You can replace your token in each file using `sed` with the bash command:

```
sed -i 's/%IP_ADDRESS%/127.0.0.1/g' *.js
```

This will do the replacement in-place (the `-i` flag) on all `.js` files in the current directory.

If you want to create a new file instead of modifying the old one, you can use the following command:

```
sed 's/%IP_ADDRESS%/127.0.0.1/g' input.js > output.js
```

In that case, you would need to repeat the command for each file.

A good alternative might be to change the Javascript code so that it loads the IP address as needed, instead of containing it hard-coded.

Comment: The OP asked to substitute the string with the result fetched from ifconfig.

Answer (score 0):

Place this bash script in the same dir with all js files.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Remark: $ip should contain your IP address, adjust cut and awk according to your OS.
ip=$(ifconfig eth1 | grep -i bcast | cut -d : -f2 | awk '{ print $1 }')
sed -i "s|%IP_ADDRESS%|$ip|g" *.js
```

Script works fine in Redhat 6.